# Calling an API with HttpWebRequest is returning a 404 error when using request stream and some data, how to fix?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, api, post, httpwebrequest

I've created a Mock API to act as a third party API that I will be using in the future.
The real API will be called with a 'username' and 'password' in a POST method, and will return HTTP Result 200, or 401.

I've created the API with `Asp.Net` MVC 5, .Net Framework 4.5, and my controller looks like this:

```
public class SingleSignOnController : ApiController
{
    [HttpPost]
    public HttpResponseMessage SignOnUser(string username, string password)
    {
        var response = this.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        return response;
    }
}
```

The windows application that will be consuming this API is created in `VB.Net` in a windows forms application, using .Net Framework 4.0.
To just test my POST call, I've created the same environment in a single form application that just calls the API, like this:

```
Private Sub ButtonCallAPI_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles ButtonCallAPI.Click
    Try
        Dim sLogin As String = "test"
        Dim sPassword As String = "test"
        Dim oData As String = "username=" & sLogin & "&password=" & sPassword
        Dim oDataStream As Byte() = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(oData)
        Dim oWebRequest As HttpWebRequest = CType(WebRequest.Create(TextBoxURL.Text), HttpWebRequest)
        oWebRequest.Method = "POST"
        oWebRequest.ContentLength = oDataStream.Length
        Dim oStream = oWebRequest.GetRequestStream
        oStream.Write(oDataStream, 0, oDataStream.Length)
        oStream.Close()

        Dim oWebResponse As HttpWebResponse = CType(oWebRequest.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)
        If oWebResponse.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK Then
            TextBoxResult.Text = "OK!"
        Else
            TextBoxResult.Text = oWebResponse.StatusCode.ToString
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        TextBoxResult.Text = ex.ToString
    End Try
End Sub
```

`TextBoxURL.Text` is equal to `http://localhost:1567/api/SingleSignOn`.

When I try to call the API, I get the 404 error as an exception.

I tried to remove "SingleSignOn" from the text, and it returns 200 (OK), even with all the data I am sending.

Now, I tried a different approach:

```
Private Sub ButtonCallAPI_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles ButtonCallAPI.Click
    Try
        Dim sLogin As String = "test"
        Dim sPassword As String = "test"
        Dim oData As String = "?username=" & sLogin & "&password=" & sPassword
        Dim oWebRequest As HttpWebRequest = CType(WebRequest.Create(TextBoxURL.Text & oData), HttpWebRequest)
        oWebRequest.Method = "POST"

        Dim oWebResponse As HttpWebResponse = CType(oWebRequest.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)
        If oWebResponse.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK Then
            TextBoxResult.Text = "OK!"
        Else
            TextBoxResult.Text = oWebResponse.StatusCode.ToString
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        TextBoxResult.Text = ex.ToString
    End Try
End Sub
```

With this code, I am getting the OK result back, however, it's not secure (I guess), because even IIS logs the whole call:

`2020-11-03 13:05:08 ::1 POST /api/SingleSignOn username=test&password=test 1567 - ::1 - - 200 0 0 211 128 68`

Why am I getting the 404 error, and how to fix it?